# Error on the Challenge: Save and Load Records with a Server-Side Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, trailhead

Error message:

> *Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
>   The campingList JavaScript controller doesn't have a 'doInit' function or doesn't call the Apex controller to get items from the database.*

I have done the actions asked for the challange, I have tested the app and it works, but the challenge says I am not calling the doInit and the apex controller.. Can someone help me? Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks!
Here is my code:

**campingList.cmp**

```
     <aura:component controller="CampingListController" implements="force:appHostable, 
flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,
force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" >
        <aura:attribute name="items" type="Camping_Item__c[]"/>
        <aura:attribute name="newItem" type="Camping_Item__c" default="{'Name':'',
                                                                       'Quantity__c':0,
                                                                       'Price__c':0,
                                                                       'Packed__c':false,
                                                                       'sobjectType':'Camping_Item__c'}"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />     
        <!-- NEW Camping FORM -->
        <div class="slds-col slds-col--padded slds-p-top--large">


            <!-- [[ Camping form goes here ]] -->

            <div aria-labelledby="newCampaingForm">

                <!-- BOXED AREA -->
                <fieldset class="slds-box slds-theme--default slds-container--small">

                    <legend id="newCampaingForm" class="slds-text-heading--small 
                                                        slds-p-vertical--medium">
                        Add Expense
                    </legend>

                    <!-- CREATE NEW Camping FORM -->
                    <form class="slds-form--stacked">

                        <div class="slds-form-element slds-is-required">
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <ui:inputText aura:id="campingName" label="Camping Name"
                                              class="slds-input"
                                              labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                                              value="{!v.newItem.Name}"
                                              required="true"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="slds-form-element slds-is-required">
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <ui:inputNumber aura:id="quantity" label="Quantity"
                                                class="slds-input"
                                                labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                                                value="{!v.newItem.Quantity__c}"
                                                required="true"/>

                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <ui:inputCurrency aura:id="price" label="Price"
                                                  class="slds-input"
                                                  labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                                                  value="{!v.newItem.Price__c}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="packed" label="Packed ?"
                                              class="slds-checkbox"
                                              labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                                              value="{!v.newItem.Packed__c}"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <ui:button label="Create Expense"
                                       class="slds-button slds-button--brand"
                                       press="{!c.createCampingList}"/>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                    <!-- / CREATE NEW EXPENSE FORM -->

                </fieldset>
                <!-- / BOXED AREA -->

            </div>
            <!-- / CREATE NEW EXPENSE -->
        </div>

        <!-- ITERATING ITEM LISTS -->
        <div class="slds-card slds-p-top--medium">

            <c:campingHeader />

            <section class="slds-card__body">
                <div id="list" class="row">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item">
                        <c:campingListItem item="{!item}"/>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>  
        <!-- / ITERATING ITEM LISTS -->



    </aura:component>
```

**campingListController.js**

```
 ({
    // Load items from Salesforce
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) 
    {

        helper.getItemsJs(component, event);

    },

    createCampingList : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("entered in the createCampingList js method");

        if(helper.validateCampingListForm(component))
        {
            console.log("entered the conditional to create the item");
            // Create the new item
            var newCampingItem = component.get("v.newItem");
            console.log("created variable on js");
            helper.createItem(component, newCampingItem);
            console.log("exit helper js");
        }               
    } 
})
```

**campingListHelper.js**

`

```
({
    getItemsJs : function (component, event)
    {
        // Create the action
        var action = component.get("c.getItems");

        // Add callback behavior for when response is received
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) 
                           {
                               var state = response.getState();
                               if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") 
                               {
                                   component.set("v.items", response.getReturnValue());
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
                               }
                           });

        // Send action off to be executed

        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    },

    createItem : function (component, newItemToSave)
    {
        console.log("entered the createItem helper method");
        var action = component.get("c.saveItem");
        console.log("created the helper action");

        action.setParams({
            "newSaveItem": newItemToSave
        });

        console.log("before the helper callback");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response)
                           {
                               var state = response.getState();
                               console.log("entered the helper callback");

                               if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                                   console.log("ok helper");
                                   var items = component.get("v.items");
                                   items.push(response.getReturnValue());
                                   component.set("v.items", items);
                                   console.log("ok helper2");
                               } 
                           });
        console.log("before helper enqueue");
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        console.log("after helper enqueue");
    },
    validateCampingListForm: function(component) 
    {
        console.log("entered in the validation method");
        var isCampingValid = true;
        var nameField = component.find("campingName");
        var quantityField = component.find("quantity");
        var priceField = component.find("price");

        if(nameField.get("v.value") == '' )
        {
            nameField.set("v.errors",[{message:"name can't be blank"}]);
            isCampingValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("name  validated");
            nameField.set("v.errors",null);
        }

        if( quantityField.get("v.value") == '' )
        {
            quantityField.set("v.errors",[{message:"Quantity can't be blank"}]);
            isCampingValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("quantity validated");
            quantityField.set("v.errors",null);
        }

        if(priceField.get("v.value") == '')
        {

            priceField.set("v.errors",[{message:"Price can't be blank"}]);
            isCampingValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("price  validated");
            priceField.set("v.errors",null); 
        }

        return(isCampingValid);
    }    
})`
```

**CampingListController.apxc**

```
    public with sharing class CampingListController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Camping_Item__c> getItems()
    {
         // Check to make sure all fields are accessible to this user
        String[] fieldsToCheck = new String[] {
            'Id', 'Name', 'Packed__c', 'CreatedDate'
                };

                    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldDescribeTokens = 
                    Schema.SObjectType.Camping_Item__c.fields.getMap();

        for(String field : fieldsToCheck) {
            if( ! fieldDescribeTokens.get(field).getDescribe().isAccessible()) {
                throw new System.NoAccessException();
                return null;
            }
        }

        // query
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Packed__c, CreatedDate FROM Camping_Item__c ORDER BY Name ASC];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Camping_Item__c saveItem (Camping_Item__c newSaveItem)
    {
        upsert newSaveItem;
        return newSaveItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: its asking you to put your helper function back into the main controller, at least for your getitems

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe it was something so simple.. haha thank you!

Comment: if it was helpful, take some time to up-vote https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155287/the-campinglist-javascript-controller-isnt-setting-the-item-as-a-parameter-or

Comment: Ok! I just did, but I need a 15 reputation in order to show it and for now I only have 13pts.

Comment: you should be able to now =P